# do we get another chance to reach shamayim if we missed our goal once?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

I have heard that there is a task for everyone to fulfill before they enter shamayim, but what happens if you had a chance to fulfill your task in life and you missed it? do you get a different task? do you still have another opportunity to go and fulfill your mission Hashem put you on earth for?!?

Comment: Thats a very interesting question. I will write a question similar to this. Look for it.

Answer (score 3):

Astounding! Read the first few chapters in Shaar HaGilgulim from the Arizal. One must fulfill all the 613 *mitzvos b'machshava b'dibbur uv'maaseh*. That means to fufill all of them in deed through speech and thought, through *limud hatorah* and the *kavanos* according to the Kabbalah. If one does not do it all in one lifetime, he gets at least three more chances.

The Mitzva of *Pesach Sheni* indicates that G-D gives second chances. We must not miss that chance in this life or else we must repeat by living in another body in another time.
For details, the *sefer* has several current translations, one of which is out of print.

Comment: Do jews believe in reincarnation? What do you mean by we have another chance?

Comment: @JimThio Some do, see here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2445/883

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide a Torah source indicating that everyone has a particular task in life?

As far as I can tell the Torah itself makes no indication that we have individual tasks/mission in life.

We must all try and develop ourselves through living a life based in Torah and reason.  We each use our given strengths and weaknesses, but primarily according to ones knowledge and relationship to God will determine ones portion in the world to come.

Thank you for considering this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

there is a concept called a "gilgal". no one really fully understands this concept but it is when your soul comes back down to earth to finish its goal in life.

Comment: I've heard enough *Megale Amukot*, *AriZal*, *R' Moshe David Valle* and others to believe that *someone* has a pretty good idea how gilgulim work. (But it's very esoteric knowledge for a reason.)

Comment: Actually if you learn even just the first few chapters of Shaar HaGilgulim you will get the feeling that what most people (many of them learned) nowadays think gilgulim are is a based on a reading of Kabbalistic sources with Buddist lenses.

Comment: @Yahu please explain.

Answer (score -1):

A person doesn't have only one mission. He has many chances to complete "his" goal.