# Reincarnation in the Hechalot Texts

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, reincarnation

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/where-does-the-concept-of-gilgulim-reincarnations-in-judaism-come-from/2460?s=7%7C0.1338#2460) claims that the idea of reincarnation is found in the Hechalot texts. Is this indeed the case, and if so, where?

---

According to R. Aryeh Kaplan [in Meditation and Kabbalah](https://books.google.com/books?id=nW_GAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=reincarnation%20hekhalot&source=bl&ots=hF-syLZ_L5&sig=buXhopfBpV0IHQByetA40NPDBNA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAmoVChMI4ufXrbXNyAIVhCQeCh2EeQtv#v=onepage&q=reincarnation%20hekhalot&f=false) reincarnation is referenced in the [Sefer HaBahir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahir). Perhaps this is what was meant by Hechalot texts.

Comment: Is this a Q&A or are you looking for more sources?

Comment: @DannySchoemann the question is only if it is in the Hechalos. This could be positively demonstrated with a citation, or negatively demonstrated by citing a source that affirms that the idea is not in the Hechalos.

Comment: After a lull, it appears that the commentless downvoter has been reincarnated.