# At Techiyas Hameisim what will happen to reincarnated souls?

Tags: soul, resurrection-of-the-dead, reincarnation

At Techiyas Hameisim what will happen to all the bodies that had souls that came down again as gilgul (that the soul had already been in another body)?

Which body will arise by Techiyas Hameisim if the soul was used in other bodies as well? 
And which wife will a man have if he remarried?

Comment: According to the opinions who don't think that gilgulim is inherently a contradiction to schar vionesh, of which techias hameisim is a part, of course.

Comment: @user6591 Can you please quote which opinions and where thnx

Comment: See some of these answers and check the sources. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/where-does-the-concept-of-gilgulim-reincarnations-in-judaism-come-from but it doesn't answer your question here. It will just give some overview on the subject.