# Does Eternal Gehinnom (i.e. Eternal Judgment leading to Eternal Punishment) negate the concept of Reincarnation?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, resurrection-of-the-dead, gehinnom, reincarnation

Where is there a rabbinic discussion of whether eternal Gehinnom (i.e. eternal judgment leading to eternal punishment) negates the concept of Reincarnation? (Because the concept of reincarnation, if true, sounds like one is able to escape such eternal consequence, if there is one.)

Comment: According to the Rambam, who elsewhere holds that Olam HaBa will come after Mashiach (Hil. Melachim 12:5), writes that the wicked who earn themselves Eternal Punishment will thereby forfeit their share in Olam HaBa (Hil. Teshuvah 8:1, 8:5, 9:1).

Comment: Some of the writings say that at times reincarnation is used to allow someone to fix the problems they caused or atone for sins of the previous life. If they fail, then punishment follows. If they succeed, then there is no need for punishment.

Comment: @DonielF please put a link here on Rambam's response and the references that you provided.

Comment: @sabbahillel please source your response, so I can enlighten myself with them.

Comment: @ninamag mainly from memory, but google Moshe Hevel or *gilgul* and look at http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6676-gilgul-neshamoth  or https://torah.org/torah-portion/perceptions-5759-zoshabracha/

Comment: @ninamag https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Repentance.8-9 and https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Kings_and_Wars.12

Comment: @sabbahillel No. You’re talking about gilgulim. The OP is talking about techias hameisim. In a gilgul you’re not reincarnated.

Comment: @DonielF I do not think that *techias hameisim* is reincarnation. I think that is more like gilgul or *rebirth*.  Reincarnation is being born in a new body during the normal world.

Comment: @sabbahillel **facepalm** Of course. Okay, so in that case my above Rambam’s also go out the window.

Comment: My question reads, "Does Eternal Gehinnom ... negate the concept of Reincarnation?" From this simple question, I am not talking about the Resurrection of the Dead. I am talking about the concept of Reincarnation that is often associated with eastern religions.

Comment: I would say not because the concept of Gehinnom would involve punishment after all attempts (via reincarnation) to allow the person to fix problems have failed. The avodas zarah concepts may differ in various aspects as each one would believe differently but each different idea would need to be addressed separately. In any case, that would have no connection with us. The concept of gilgul or reincarnation would not cancel the idea of final reward or punishment.

Comment: @DonielF What are you talking about? Rambam doesnt hold that olam haba comes after mashiacי. Nor does he say that in Melakhim 12:5.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is assuming the reincarnation of the OP is not rival of the dead, as clarified in the comments, but is referring to what is commonly called Gilgul Neshamos.

As I mention in my answer to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2443/where-does-the-concept-of-gilgulim-reincarnations-in-judaism-come-from) Mi Yodea question, the wise men of Luniel mention this idea to the [Rashba](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashba), written in his responsa 418.
Rashba did not argue against their logic, but he didn't vocally endorse it either. His having printed can be taken as having accepted it.

However, there are two points which I'll mention that negate the argument.

The first point is according to most Kabbalistic works that I've seen which discuss the subject of Gilgul, such as Chida and Ben Yehoyada.
The entire soul is not transmigrated to a new body. Rather, a 'spark' (nitzutz) of the old soul which needs fixing is attached to a new soul. So the old soul who sinned is still punished in Gehinom, hell, while that spark that needs fixing is in a new host on earth.

The second point is not something I've seen in books but have heard some Rabbis say. Being sent back as a Gilgul is more painful to the soul than Gehinom. If that is true, the returning itself is in fact punishment and the soul was not spared any punishment by this process.
(As noted I've never seen this inside and can't vouch for it's truthfulness.)

Comment: @user6591 Thank you for an insightful answer. Please tell me what possible definitions or understandings of Reincarnation are there? 'My question reads, "Does Eternal Gehinnom ... negate the concept of Reincarnation?" I only am familiar with one type that is often associated with eastern religions, whereby the dead comes back as a different entity (human or animal), and then once dead, comes back again as a different entity.

Comment: @ninamag I understand. But in the comments section people were confusing it with the revival of the dead. I opened my answer by pointing out that you clarified exactly what you meant and had correctly called reincarnation. Jews who discuss reincarnation refer to it as Gilgul as I wrote in my answer. You can research more by using that word. As far as I know, no Jew ever discussed it while we still lived amongst those eastern religions. It was popularized amongst Jews in Israrl and then other middle eastern countries and Europe around 500 years ago. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgul